# Facebook Like with Send on a mobile Web page

Tags: mobile, facebook-like, send

My experience is that Facebook Like works fine on mobile pages in general, but I now also want to add the Send/Share button.

When I click on the Send button the window being opened is so large (clearly more than 320 pixels wide) that it instead is shown almost completely outside of the display to the left (the right edge of the window being just beside the Send button).

Is there a way via the Social Plugins or via the API to create a Send/Share form that would fit inside of 320 pixels?

I've worked with the Graph API before, so that would not be a show-stopper.

Thanks in advance,
Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this send dialog.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

And try forcing the display mode to `wap`

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display